# Find out all running node.js application with pid and port

Tags: node.js, express

I have to find all running node.js app on machine with pid and port along with path and then following path I would like to find all classes then functions inside classes. Example suppose we have 2 separate independent node application with different folder and want to find as mentioned above.I tried hard but not find solution. I have to implement this functionality for client project. Is this possible and if possible then how it be done?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks! Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are a couple of ways to do this -

- pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout.

`pgrep node`

- Process command (ps)

`ps ax` will give the full list of processes and adding a 'u' option gives detailed information. i.e. `ps aux`
To search for a particular process `grep` command is used, so for nodejs, it would be `ps aux | grep node`

- Network Statistics (netstat)

`netstat -a | more` : To show both listening and non-listening sockets

`netstat -at` : To list all tcp ports.

`netstat -l` : To list only the listening ports.

`netstat -lt` : To list only the listening tcp ports.

`netstat -pt` : To display the PID and program names

So as [chris-lam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049109/chris-lam) has suggested `netstat -lntp | grep node` would list all the listening TCP ports running as a node  process.

To use it within code following piece of code can be helpful -

```
const {exec} = require('child_process'); 
exec('ps aux | grep node', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the port and PID with the `netstat` command.

```
netstat -lntp | grep node
```

`ps` allows you to find the full command of the process:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

Comment: can we use above command in nodejs script or shell script or in any file to execute it later?

Comment: Yes but your node application must be run as root in order to have permission to run the `netstat` or `ps` commands.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling and researching, this is the way I found the easier one for me.
I didn't found yet a one-liner, so my solution is composed by 2 commands:

```
ps aux | grep node
```

it wil return all node process with pids and paths

```
netstat -lntp | grep node
```

it will return pids and ports

Using them together with

```
ps aux | grep node && netstat -lntp | grep node
```

Will give you something like this:

[image]

So if you want to know which app is using which port, you can look for the port from the output of second command, take the pid from the last column and from that you can lookup the pid in the output from first command: from there you should be able to understand the path of the program using that port.

It's not very elegant but it's the easier way I found