# Manage running yarn node.js localhost ports?

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, localhost, yarnpkg

Is there a way to list active localhost ports that were run using `npm run serve` / `yarn serve`?
The problem is that I have several projects running on port 8080 and 8081 and after system restart they also remain active,

1. is there a way to list them out in terminal / cmd / gitbash?
2. is there a way disable / shut them down using command prompt?

Upd.:
I also tried to run `localhost:8088` as mentioned in the yarn documantation but it didn't work.

Comment: Here i found a duplicate of your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56285399/find-out-all-running-node-js-application-with-pid-and-port

Answer (score 0):

The solution was obvious: the running processes (server sockets) didn't close because I haven't restarted the system, I only hibernated it. System restart made the thing.

Although obtaining a list of node ports through a one-line command, managing them from npm / node would still be a cool thing. Especially for those who deal with DevOps in one way or another.